# Celery gives Error No Nodes replied within time on doing Celery Control Shutdown

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celeryd

I want to kill a Celery App being used in another Service . Found out a command upon research-

`Celery Control Shutdown`

This Command Successfully Kills All the Processes but ends with a Error

`Error : No Nodes Replied within Time Constraint.`

PS:- We don't want to use PS Commands to Kill the Celery.
Is there any other way to kill Celery Processes?
Also, What could possibly be the reason for this error, if the command is fulfilling its purpose and functionality ?

We Tried -

`Celery Control Shutdown`

This Command Successfully Kills All the Processes but ends with a Error .

Other Commands like given below are working fine.

```
celery worker -A my_app -l INFO
celery -A project inspect stats
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Help Me Understand , what could be the probable issue for the Error?
Thanks